# ARC Semantic Issue (Xcode) for Flutter Webview

Tags: ios, flutter, wkwebview, flutter-ios-build

I am using a Flutter package named `webview_flutter (4.2.0)`, and facing an error when I try to run my application on iOS device, there is an error message saying that

`ARC Semantic Issue (Xcode): No visible @interface for 'FWFWebView' declares the selector 'setInspectable:' /Users/xxx/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/webview_flutter_wkwebview-3.6.0/ios/Classes/FWFWebViewHostApi.m:203:44`

So I try to check the error in my XCode (14.2), there is a condition checking on the iOS version as shown in the image below.

[image]

Is there anyone know how to solve it, thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try add to your `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependency_overrides:
  webview_flutter_wkwebview: '3.5.0'
```

Comment: But this is only a temporary solution, keep waiting for release updates